# Endorsement failure in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 83d5de17fa5569456cdd4205808455177bde8953e2b1e4f7c59100c3f76559f0: invalid invocation: chaincode 'CVT' is already initialized but called as init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are submitting a transaction that is flagged as an initialization transaction to a chaincode that has already been initialized. An initialization transaction must only be called once for each deployment of a chaincode.

See the description of initialization in the **Approve a chaincode definition for your organization** section of this page in the Hyperledger Fabric documentation for a more thorough explanation:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/chaincode_lifecycle.html#step-three-approve-a-chaincode-definition-for-your-organization